# What determines which system calls a program makes?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, system-calls

So i have a C/C++ program which does not run a certain computer system simulator because it makes a system call that is not implemented in that simulator. Now I am wondering what determines what system calls a program makes. Is it only the compiler? or do things such as OS and hardware play a role as well. The simulator was tested on ubuntu 14.04 so I was wondering if compiling the program on a ubuntu 14.04 system might yield different system calls made by the program?

Some context info:
My own computer is running Windows 10 (64-bit) and I am compiling a program in VS code using a wsl terminal. I want to run this program on a computer system simulator called Multi2Sim. I am running this simulator in a docker container on my windows computer. When running `lsb_release -a` in the docker containers terminal it yields `ubuntu 14.04`. The program does not run on the simulator because it makes the system call getdents64() which is not implemented in the simulator yet.

The simulator was tested on ubuntu 14.04 so I was thinking maybe if I compiled on that os instead it would change the system calls. I used the `-m32` flag because the simulator does not support 64-bit ELF files.

Some outputs showing what versions of compilers etc that im running:
When running `uname -a` in the container I get:

```
Linux 66510ea7ce2e 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`g++ --version` on my windows computer in the wsl terminal:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
```

`g++ -dumpmachine` on my windows computer in the wsl terminal:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Makefile:

````
TARGET =    bandwidth

.PHONY: all clean $(TARGET)

# directories
INC_DIR = ../include
KERN_DIR = ../kernels
CMN_DIR = ../common
OBJ_DIR = obj


# compiler flags
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -m32 -O3 -fopenmp -march=native -I$(INC_DIR) -std=c++14 $(USER_DEFS)


# header files
HEADERS = $(wildcard $(INC_DIR)/*.h)


# src files
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard $(KERN_DIR)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(CMN_DIR)/*.cpp)

# object files
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)
    
clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJ)
    @rm -rf $(TARGET)
    @echo "Cleaned..."
    
%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@```
````

Comment: Depends on the architecture too.

Comment: standard library implementation, other library, your code.

Comment: Wen need more context information.

Comment: In C or C++ terms, it is the implementation.    The implementation is what translates source code into an executable form.   Practically, the implementation consists of the build chain (compiler, linker, etc) and the translation it performs depends on the host platform (e.g. hardware, instruction set architecture, operating system installed, available libraries, etc).  Naturally, the implementation may utilise some system calls supported by the host system.  Practically, build options (e.g. for the compiler or linker) may affect the choice between using particular system calls or alternatives.

Comment: does not run a simulator, or does not run _on_ a simulator? Reading the question, I can't be sure what environments you have, the one that software works in, and the one it doesn't. Ubuntu 14.04 vs. some newer Ubuntu? Another OS entirely? Different hardware, as in x86 vs. ARM?

Comment: note standard library is  usually a shared dynamic library, so if system uses different version of standard library system calls can be different. Same applies to all other shared library your program uses.

Comment: @ilkkachu So the program does not run on a simulator because it makes the system call getdents64(). I compiled it on windows 10 (64-bit) using gcc and g++ 5.4.0 respectively. The simulator was tested on ubuntu 14.04 so i was thinking maybe if i compiled on that os instead it would change the system calls. I used the -m32 flag because the simulator does not support 64-bit ELF files.

Comment: This is still pretty unclear. You say you're building on Windows, but what is your target system, the system that your simulator simulates?

Comment: On Linux, you can use `strace` or a debugger to get a callstack when system calls are performed. That'll show you where this system call is coming from.

Comment: @Daniel123643 Please [edit] your question to add information instead of writing comments. What simulator are you referring to? What are your host OS and guest OS?

Comment: @Bodo added some context in the original question now

Comment: @molbdnilo target is ubuntu 14.04. Have added some additional information in my question now-

Comment: The details about your compiler and OS are still not clear yet. Assuming you run Linux (Ubuntu) in your simulator, please copy&paste the output of `uname -a` in the different simulators, where the program runs and where it doesn't. If the simulators are configured differently, show the differences. When you build the program on Windows, what compiler exactly do you use? Show the output of `g++ --version` and `g++ -dumpmachine`

Comment: @Bodo added the outputs of all of those calls now, thanks. uname -a was run on the docker container (where the simulator is running) and g++ --version and g++ -dumpmachine was run on my actual machine where i compiled the program.

Comment: It is still not clear yet what (virtual, real, simulated) machines and OS you have. Please describe this in your question in a clear way. The output `Linux 66510ea7ce2e 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2` indicates Windows Subsystem for Linux. Where in your setup do you use Windows? Why did you remove context information from the question? I will re-add it.

Comment: @Bodo Sorry I may be misunderstanding you. I tried to re-clarify some context on my system. Does it make it any clearer or is it still not understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What determines which system calls a program makes?

The source code of the program. The *entire* program including all the compiled sources that have been linked together. Including those that you didn't specify explicitly, most notably the the C system library where most system calls will directly originate. In case of Ubuntu, that would be the glibc. Of course, the other sources that call system library functions will indirectly affect the system calls.

> Is it only the compiler

Not *only* the compiler of course, but it too is responsible for some of these indirect calls. For example, if you write `new X`, then the compiler generates a call to `malloc` whose implementation calls `sbrk` or `mmap` whose implementations do system calls.

Comment: There's also the dynamic loader, and maybe one wants to count the language runtime separately.

Comment: The source code doesn't determine what system calls the program makes.   If you supply the same source to two different toolchains, on different operating systems, and the code is successfully translated (e.g. compiled and linked to produce an executable) then the same code will almost certainly result in a different set of system calls.   And, BTW, there is no requirement that a `new` expression generate a call to `malloc()` - and calls like `sbrk()` or `mmap()` are system specific.

Comment: @Peter "Different toolchains" have different sources. Those sources contain the calls that they make.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I understand the informatioin in the question in this way:

- You compile your program in a virtual Ubuntu system (WSL) on your real Windows system. - You run Ubuntu (WSL) in a docker container on your real Windows system.
- In this virtual Ubuntu (WSL) you run Multi2Sim which is supposed to simulate the Linux ABI.

According to the documentation, the simulation of system calls seems to be incomplete. See section *2.3 Compiling and Simulating Your Own Source Code* in
http://www.multi2sim.org/downloads/m2s-guide-4.2.pdf,

The system call `getdents64()` vs. `getdents()` is not about 64-bits processor architecture but about kernel support for large file systems.

Citing https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents64.2.html :

> Library support for getdents64() was added in glibc 2.30

It might help to compile and statically link your program with an older version of the `glibc` library.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thank you for being patient with me. I will attempt to statically link the program as suggested. Thank you so much!